# git make your local branch remote, local branch already has an upstream

Tags: git, git-remote

Currently I have a branch that has an upstream (remote branch).

I have made some commits so, my local branch is e.g. 9 commits ahead of the remote branch.

I want to create a new remote branch and change the tracking remote branch to this branch.

Should I first have to unset the upstream and then push the local branch to remote or it does not matter?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To push to a new remote branch and track it with the local branch:

```
git push -u origin local_branch:new_remote_branch
```

Comment: thanks, this will automatically set the new remote branch as a stream?

Comment: Just to be sure you can stick in the `-u` (or --set-upstream) parameter.